# How to loop a dictionary with 2-dimensional keys?

Tags: python

I have viewed many other questions with similar titles but mine is different. So I am posting it here.

I have a dictionary:

```
d={('a','1'):4,('a','2'):5,('b','1'):6,('b','2'):10}
```

I call `'a'`,`'b'` words and `'1'`,`'2'` tags. I also have

```
tags=('1','2')
```

and

```
d2={'1':10,'2':15}
```

I need to perform a calculation so for each tag I have distribution of words: For tag `'1'`, I need `{'a':0.4,'b':0.6}`.

Here is my code:

```
for tag in tags:
    dist_tag = {}
    for word in d[tag].keys():
        dist_tag[word] = d[tag][word]/d2[tag]
```

The above code has error message saying `KeyError: '1'`. How can I make it work?

Comment: d dictionary has no key '1'... d['1'].keys()

Comment: For tag `'1'`, I understand. But when you do for tag `'2'` in the next iteration, you will replace the results for tag `'1'` since dictionary cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: @theausome thanks for providing a solution! this loop does have other parts to it (leveraging the output of dist_tag) which I didn't include because it has no impact on issue I am facing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keys of `d` are tuples, but you're trying to use a single string as the key.

To make the correct keys you can use nested for loops. Like this:

```
d = {('a', '1'): 4, ('a', '2'): 5, ('b', '1'): 6, ('b', '2'): 10}
words = ('a', 'b')
tags = ('1', '2')
d2 = {'1': 10, '2': 15}

for tag in tags:
    dist_tag = {}
    for word in words:
        key = word, tag
        dist_tag[word] = d[key] / d2[tag]
    print(tag, dist_tag)
```

**output**

```
1 {'a': 0.4, 'b': 0.6}
2 {'a': 0.3333333333333333, 'b': 0.6666666666666666}
```

As fferri notes, you don't need that `key = word, tag` assignment, you can simply do

```
dist_tag[word] = d[word, tag] / d2[tag]
```

I wrote it with `key` just to make it a little clearer, but both versions are quite acceptable.

---

If you want to collect the `dist_tag`s rather than print them in the loop, you can do this:

```
dist_tags = {}
for tag in tags:
    dist_tag = {}
    for word in words:
        dist_tag[word] = d[word, tag] / d2[tag]
    dist_tags[tag] = dist_tag

print(dist_tags)
```

**output**

```
{'1': {'a': 0.4, 'b': 0.6}, '2': {'a': 0.3333333333333333, 'b': 0.6666666666666666}}
```

That can be condensed using a dict comprehension:

```
dist_tags = {}
for tag in tags:
    dist_tags[tag] = {word: d[word, tag] / d2[tag] for word in words}
print(dist_tags)
```

Or if you're feeling brave, a nested dict comp:

```
dist_tags = {tag: {word: d[word, tag] / d2[tag] for word in words} for tag in tags}
print(dist_tags)
```

---

FWIW, we can also extract `words` and `tags` from `d` with a list comp or generator expression:

```
d = {('a', '1'): 4, ('a', '2'): 5, ('b', '1'): 6, ('b', '2'): 10}
words, tags = (tuple(sorted(set(u))) for u in zip(*d.keys()))
print(words, tags)
```

**output**

```
('a', 'b') ('1', '2')
```

Comment: You can use `d[word, tag]` as well.

Comment: @fferri Most certainly!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
d = {('a','1'):4,('a','2'):5,('b','1'):6,('b','2'):10}
tags = ('1','2')
d2 = {'1':10,'2':15}

newd = {}
for tag in tags:
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k[1] == tag:
            newd.update({k[0]: v/d2[tag]})

    print(newd)

# {'a': 0.40000000000000002, 'b': 0.59999999999999998}
# {'a': 0.33333333333333331, 'b': 0.66666666666666663}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? There's nothing particularly wrong with this code. Although naturally I prefer mine, which is slightly more efficient, since it doesn't need that `if` . :)